# How to make my homepage reload completely (including cache) when refreshed normally?

Tags: html, http, caching, browser, reload

I constantly update my homepage with new details, and founded out that unfortunately I can not observe these changes by simply reloading the page, and I should use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> (cache refresh).

Is there any way, like a line of code to put in the source, in order to make my homepage reload completely when the page is refreshed, without pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd>?

Answer (score 0):

If you can alter the HTTP headers sent with your homepage, do the following:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers) for more info.

If you can't, try the following in your HTML document:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
```

This won't work on most proxy caches, and it may not work on some browsers.  More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers).